# Rights under Israel aviation services law

Tags: legal, israel, aircraft, delays, connecting-flights

I had a plane ticket issued by Hainan Airlines to travel from Hong Kong (HKG) to Tel Aviv (TLV) via Shanghai Pudong (PVG). The Hong Kong - Shanghai Pudong leg (HX232) was operated by Hong Kong Airlines and was delayed due to "operational reason and flow control". As a result of the delay, I missed the Shanghai Pudong - Tel Aviv leg (HU407).

The airline did not inform me of my rights under Israeli Aviation Service law back then, but offered to strand me in Shanghai and fly me to Tel Aviv 3 days later. I couldn't afford the long delay and paid another airline to fly me to Tel Aviv.

Am I entitled to any compensation from the airline (new plane ticket / delay?) under Israel aviation services law? I'm not very sure if it covers such a situation after reading it. Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

References: http://www.tourism-law.co.il/pdf/AviationServicesLawENG.pdf

---

Update: Thanks for all your help. Even though I'm still unsure if this law is applicable to my case, quoting it did help me negotiate a deal with the airlines.

Comment: You should, probably, consult a lawer regarding this issue.

Comment: Likely no as ATC is not in the airlines control but you can still file a claim and see what happens.

Comment: What makes you think Israeli laws are at all relevant? The flight originated outside of Israel and was operated by a non-Israeli airline. Even EU's laws wouldn't have helped you out here.

Comment: @JonathanReez, The Israeli tourism services law applies to all flights to and from Israel, including non-Israeli airlines. See the definition of a flight in [the PDF linked by the OP](http://www.tourism-law.co.il/pdf/AviationServicesLawENG.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Israeli law gives you compensation in case of cancellation. A delay of 8 hours, at take off, is considered cancellation. However, it's not clear how this applies for you.

[This law forum question (Hebrew)](http://www.lawguide.co.il/forum/%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%94/?m=178422) describes a very similar case (small delay of first section leading to missed connection), and the lawyer says they're not entitled to compensation, because there was no delay at take off. However, in that case the passenger did fly to the final destination with the same carrier the next day.

In case of cancellation, you'd be entitled to either an alternative flight or a full refund, as well as compensation of about 3,000 ILS (depending on distance). I don't think you can claim the refund (because the flight wasn't cancelled), but perhaps you can get the refund.

It further depends on what you did with the return leg. If you used your return ticket, you're unlikely to get a full refund. If you bought an alternative 2-way ticket, there's a better chance.